# Azure Cognitive Services - Vision API single call results in 9 transactions

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cognitive-services

I am using below method to detect text in an image. But a single execution of this method results in 9 transactions in my Azure dashboard. Can someone please guide if I am missing something? or is there anything wrong with the code?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertToText(string url)
        {
            string subscriptionKey = "jfh3879rhf4389terhkjy86";

            ComputerVisionClient computerVision = new ComputerVisionClient(
                new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey),
                new System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[] { });

            // Specify the Azure region
            computerVision.Endpoint = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";


            if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute))
            {
                return null;
            }

            TextRecognitionMode textRecognitionMode = TextRecognitionMode.Printed;
            int numberOfCharsInOperationId = 36;

            // Start the async process to recognize the text
            RecognizeTextHeaders textHeaders =
                await computerVision.RecognizeTextAsync(url, textRecognitionMode);

            // Retrieve the URI where the recognized text will be
            // stored from the Operation-Location header
            string operationId = textHeaders.OperationLocation.Substring(
                textHeaders.OperationLocation.Length - numberOfCharsInOperationId);

            TextOperationResult result =
                await computerVision.GetTextOperationResultAsync(operationId);

            // Wait for the operation to complete
            int i = 0;
            int maxRetries = 10;
            while ((result.Status == TextOperationStatusCodes.Running ||
                    result.Status == TextOperationStatusCodes.NotStarted) && i++ < maxRetries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server status: {0}, waiting {1} seconds...", result.Status, i);
                await Task.Delay(1000);

                result = await computerVision.GetTextOperationResultAsync(operationId);
            }

            // Display the results
            var lines = result.RecognitionResult.Lines;
            string details = "";

            foreach (Line line in lines)
            {
                details += line.Text + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            return Content(details);
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at what that `while` statement does, for instance through logging? Problem might be there?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [Cognitive Services pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/):

> **What constitutes a transaction for Computer Vision API?**
>   For Recognize Text each POST call counts as a transaction. All GET calls to see the results of the async service are counted as transactions but are free of charge.

My guess would be that the 'issue' is in the `while`-statement since you're getting the result while the job is (possibly) still running. You're probably getting the status a couple of times before the job is done. The good thing: those API calls are free.

I see your code is the same as in the [Quickstart: Extract text using the Computer Vision SDK and C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/csharp-hand-text-sdk), so it should be OK.

Comment: Thank you so much rickvdbosch for the explanation. Yes the code is actually from the example in Quickstart. Is there any way to avoid while statement ?